# Require ldap-group on apache 2 vhost fails when trying to log in

Tags: apache-2.2, ldap, authentication, virtualhost

I have a vhost which I'm trying to get to work with LDAP-authentication. My configuration looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost 0.0.0.0:80>
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/root/"
        ServerName myServerName
        ServerAlias http://myServerName.com/
        LogLevel debug
        ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/svn_error_log"
        CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/svn_access_log" common

        <Directory "/var/www/root/">
                Allow from all
                DirectoryIndex index.php
        </Directory>

        <Location "/">
                AuthType Basic
                AuthBasicProvider ldap
                AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
                AuthName "Auth"
                AuthLDAPURL "myLDAPURL"
                AuthLDAPBindDN "myLDAPBindDN"
                AuthLDAPBindPassword my-safe-password
                Require ldap-group OU=Users,OU=A,DC=B,DC=C,DC=D
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

When I try to login, it refuses my authentication and states in the log:

```
auth_ldap authenticate: using URL myLDAPURL
auth_ldap authenticate: accepting username
auth_ldap authorise: require group: testing for group membership in "OU=Users,OU=A,DC=B,DC=C,DC=D"
auth_ldap authorise: require group: testing for member:  CN=username,OU=Users,OU=A,DC=B,DC=C,DC=D (OU=Users,OU=A,DC=B,DC=C,DC=D)
auth_ldap authorise: require group "OU=Users,OU=A,DC=B,DC=C,DC=D": authorisation failed [Comparison no such attribute (adding to cache)][No such attribute]
auth_ldap authorise: require group: testing for uniquemember: CN=username,OU=Users,OU=A,DC=B,DC=C,DC=D (OU=Users,OU=A,DC=B,DC=C,DC=D)
auth_ldap authorise: require group "OU=Users,OU=A,DC=B,DC=C,DC=D": authorisation failed [Comparison no such attribute (adding to cache)][No such attribute]
auth_ldap authorise: declining to authorise (not authoritative)
access to / failed, reason: require directives present and no Authoritative handler.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

I tried `AuthzLDAPAuthoritative On` with the same result. Also I'm sure, the LDAP is working properly, since when I only `Require valid-user` instead of an ldap-group, it works fine.

Comment: you have a require-ldap group statement that points to a ou, not a group.

Answer (score 0):

Should you be using `Require ldap-group` instead of `Require group`?

Also, if group members are identified by values of, say, the `uniquemember` attribute of the LDAP group, then you'll need to add `AuthLDAPGroupAttribute uniquemember`.

Comment: There must have gone something wrong while copying the config. I'm using `Require ldap-group`, not `group`. I'm going to edit the question. For the second part: How exactly can I find out, with which attribute the group members are identified?

Comment: `ldapsearch -b OU=A,DC=B,DC=C,DC=D ou=users` and look for an attribute that holds the member names.  Or, depending on your LDAP configuration, the group memberships may be attached to the user entries.

Comment: `ldapsearch` with the parameters as you suggested, returns nothing.

Comment: Is your LDAP Active Directory? There is a difference between how group membership is enumerated between RFC2307 and 2307bis. Also might try changing Require ldap-group to require valid-user to make sure it's working with out the group restriction.

Comment: As I wrote, I already checked `Require valid-user` to make sure, it worked. What exactly do you mean with "Is your LDAP Active Directory"?

Comment: He is asking if you are you using OpenLDAP or Microsoft Active Directory (or other).